# How do I create all of the possible combinations of a list's terms in Python?

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I need to create *all* combinations of the terms in a list. I've tried using all the parts of `itertools`, such as `permutations`, `combinations`, `combinations_with_replacement`, but all of them seem to almost 'count' up. For example, using this code:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
hex_chars = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"]
perm = combinations_with_replacement(hex_chars, 5) 
for i in list(perm): 
    print(i)
```

It produces:

```
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '1')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '2')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '3')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '4')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '5')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '6')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '7')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '8')
('0', '0', '0', '0', '9')
('0', '0', '0', '0', 'a')
('0', '0', '0', '0', 'b')
('0', '0', '0', '0', 'c')
('0', '0', '0', '0', 'd')
('0', '0', '0', '0', 'e')
('0', '0', '0', '0', 'f')
('0', '0', '0', '1', '1')
```

I need it to produce literally every possible combination, for example, you'll notice it doesn't produce "000010", and if left for long enough, it won't produce strings such as "A000A". I need to produce all of the combinations (including duplicates) that have a string-length of 5, and then I need to save them all to external text file. And, to clarify, I mean literally every single possible combination, such as "A0000", "0A000", "00A00", "000A00", "0000A0", "00000A".

Comment: That's not a combination - `00010` is the same as `00001`, as far as combinations is concerned (similarly for `a000a` and `000aa`).

Comment: lst = list(itertools.product(hex_chars, repeat=5))

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I need every string combination possible, in every possible sequence, so I need a000a, 0a00a, 00a0a, 000aa, 10000, 01000, 00100, 00010, 00001, and i viewed the duplicate before posting this, and it does not fix my problem

Comment: The answer to the duplicate *does* provide that, so please clarify in more detail what you still need to know.

Answer (score -1):

```
from itertools import permutations
perm = permutations(hex_chars, 5)
while a:
    try: 
        print(next(a))
    except:
        pass
```

Didn't notice the duplicate part at first, I guess you can type each char 5 times